# What is つい doing in the middle of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, katakana, conjunctions

What is the purpose of つい in this sentence?

> うんうん、楽しくてついエキサイトして、熱くなっちゃった

And does エキサイトして just mean "getting excited"? For context they were talking about a game they played.

Comment: 'unintentionally'

Comment: [つい](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84/#je-49551)

Comment: This post may help you: [ついかっとなってしまう meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25877/)

Comment: Thanks for the links and resources, I think I understand now.